# Angular 4: How do we write a CSS class for an element with a separate CSS file?

Tags: css, angular

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<div class="over"> Content </div>
```

This in my component file:

```
 @Component({
        selector: 'app',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: [
            './css/custom.css'
        ],
    })
```

This  is my CSS:

```
.over{
        background: #F3F3F3;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px #cccccc solid !important;
    } 
    .over:hover{
        background: white;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: 0px #cccccc solid !important;
    }
```

Folder Structure:

- app

  - css

    - custom.css
  - app.component.ts
  - app.component.html

The hover CSS isn't working here. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: So `<div class="over"> Content </div>` exists within `app.component.html`?

Comment: Yes that is in app.component.html

Comment: hover works for me, maybe the path to the css file is wrong?

Comment: You can also import the css file inside the html file, btw

Comment: most probably your path to css is wrong.

Comment: Have added folder structure in the question, if it is the CSS path issue, what would be the correct path?

Comment: but the styles for `.over` are loaded?

Comment: No, the styles are not loaded, that is what I am not able to understand.

Comment: try to clear cache and reserve the app

Comment: If the file structure is as you wrote and the code is as you wrote, all should work fine. There's nothing wrong with it. Only things I could think of; Check for a typo in code or filename. Honestly, I've overlooked typos in file-names numerous times. Perhaps a capitalization on filename, or css-class 'Over' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute path to your styles, it should work that way:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        'app/css/custom.css'
    ],
})
```

Working app with the same directory structure: https://plnkr.co/edit/cGGybOOjgsUqZwEWyaLX?p=preview